# Add recursively to vector with points c++

Tags: c++

What I want to do is get the input of two names and then store it in the database.

For example the first name would always be the advisor and the second is the student.

Example:

**Input:**

John Steven

John Barry

John Harold

**Output:**

Advisor: John

Students:Steven,Barry,Harold

I want my program to take John and put him in the first entry of the vector dataBase and then I want to take Steven Barry and Harold and put them all in the vector children.

My code so far just takes two advisors and three students. 
However, I want to be able to do this for how many advisors and students the user wants to enter.

I'm guessing from what I've read I can do this recursively but not sure how.

Any other ideas/suggestions are welcomed.

Code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string name;
    node * parent;
    vector<node*> children;

};


int main()
{
    vector<node*> dataBase;
    node *advisor, *student, *advisor2, *student2, *student3;
    advisor = new node;
    student = new node;
    advisor2 = new node;
    student2 = new node;
    student3 = new node;

    //Add a student to advisor 1
    cin>>advisor->name>>student->name;
    advisor->children.push_back(student);
    dataBase.push_back(advisor);

    //Add another student to advisor 1
    cin>>student3->name;
    advisor->children.push_back(student3);

    //Add another advisor and add a student to him
    cin>>advisor2->name>>student2->name;
    advisor2->children.push_back(student2);
    dataBase.push_back(advisor2);


    for(int i=0; i<dataBase.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Advisor:"<<endl;
        cout<<dataBase[i]->name<<endl;
        cout<<"Students:"<<endl;
        for(int j=0; j<dataBase[i]->children.size(); j++)
        {
            cout<<dataBase[i]->children[j]->name<<endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `new` and pointers? Also, you may find *iteration* instead of *recursion* more helpful for this problem.

Comment: No need for recursion here. You already have a loop for the output; maybe you could use a loop for the input as well?

Comment: I'm supposed to use pointers to put it in a tree like the advisor is the parent and then the students are the children of the advisor.. and then we are supposed to take that tree and put it in the database where we can have more than one tree (more than one advisor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a more straightforward way would be to use a map to a vector.

```
map<string, vector<string> > students_of_advisor;
while (cin) {
   cin >> advisor >> student;
   students_of_advisor[advisor].push_back(student);
}
```

Then you can print them.

```
for(auto iter=students_of_advisor.begin();
    iter != students_of_advisor.end();
    ++iter)
{
    cout<<"Advisor:"<<endl;
    cout<<iter->first<<endl;
    cout<<"Students:"<<endl;
    for(unsigned j=0; j != iter->second.size(); ++j)
    {
        cout << iter->second[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: or use a multiset, or have the map go the other direction if every student has at most one advisor.

Comment: I've never used a map so I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a simple matter of a vector-valued map:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> db_map;

int main()
{
    db_map m;

    std::string advisor, student;
    while (get(advisor, student))   // pseudo-code
    {
        m[advisor].push_back(student);
    }
}
```

The `get` pseudo-code should be something like [your usual I/O input loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9353047/596781), either using `std::getline` or `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Would be much easier for you if you use `std::map` for this:

```
std::map<string, vector<string> > myDB;

std::string line, advisor, student;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::istringstream os(line);
    os >> advisor;
    os >> student;
    myDB[advisor].push_back(student);
}
```

where `myDB` is `map` that stores `vector` of students for every advisor. You are able to access students directly by using name of advisor: `myDB[advisor]`.

This code requires following includes: `<iostream>`, `<string>`, `<sstream>`, `<vector>` and `<map>`.

Comment: `set`? What if there are two students of the same name? Like "Murphy"?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah, vector is probably better here. I have edited it.

Comment: Could have gone with a multiset, but a vector has better memory locality, which is also why map-vector may be better than a straight multimap. Anyway, you have to change `insert`, too.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Good catch. Haven't realized that one.